# Mysql min query

Tags: mysql

Any advice would be great:

I am running a `MIN()` query where I have an account number with the same status and two different timestamps

ex:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`created_at`) as date, 
  account_id, 
  changed_by_id, 
  status 
FROM statuses 
WHERE `changed_to` = 'entered' 
AND account_id = 49794;
```

results:

```
date          account_id   changed_by_id  status
2011-04-05  49794        17             entered
2011-03-16  49794        18             entered
```

when I try to extract the `min(DATE(created_at))` and `GROUP By account_id` I'm not getting the correct `changed_by_id` for that `account_id` and `date`

can anyone advise what I need to do with the query to get the matching `date` with the `changed_by_id`?

Thanks

Comment: It is a typical groupwise max query.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but it's something similar to this

```
select 
t1.DATE(`created_at`) as date, 
t1.account_id, 
t1.changed_by_id, 
t1.status 
from statuses t1
where  (date(created_at) = (select min(date(created_at))
              from statuses t2
              where t1.account_id=t2.account_id))
and t1.account_id = 49794;
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by the date, and select the first row only:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`created_at`) as date, 
  account_id, 
  changed_by_id, 
  status 
FROM statuses 
WHERE `changed_to` = 'entered' 
AND account_id = 49794
ORDER BY 1
LIMIT 1;
```

This may not be the most elegant option, but it's both clear to understand and efficient.